# How to access phpMyAdmin after installation?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've installed phpmyadmin `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`. Of course, I have also mysql and a web server running properly.

Now how can I reach it?

Comment: It depends on what web server you're using and how you set it up?

Comment: Read [phpMyAdmin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin) from ubuntu documentation

Answer (score 139):

Did you try `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`?

Edit: Do this first

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

add this line somewhere

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

and finally restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: yes. And it doesn't work.  "http://localhost" is working properly, since it display me the standard web page of the server.

Comment: Worked for me, weird though, since it worked on another server without adding this line...

Comment: This worked for me: `ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-phpmyadmin`

Comment: I tried adding the `Include` and I got a `fail` while restarting.

Comment: hello myphpadmin page is not started.what should i do?

Comment: I get "404 - Not Found"

Answer (score 25):

You probably skiped the configure from the package.

Try this cli:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

And when it choose the webserver to configure, select apache.

Comment: Simply forgot to tick the [ ] apache with the spacebar on install.

Comment: I also discovered that the little red square is not an “accept” symbol!

Answer (score 8):

It depends on your configuration.

From my experience, I may reach with localhost/phpmyadmin but fail to login, I have to reconfigure phpmyadmin, reset MySQL password, and then I may login without problems.

1. Reconfigure phpmyadmin
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to launch terminal
3. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`
4. Connection method for MySQL database for phpmyadmin: `unix socket`
5. Name of the database's administrative user: `root`
6. Password of the database's administrative user: `mysqlsamplepassword`
7. MySQL username for phpmyadmin: `root`
8. MySQL database name for phpmyadmin: `phpmyadmin`
9. Web server to reconfigure automatically: `apache2`
10. ERROR 1045
11. ignore
12. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`
13. New password for the MySQL "root" user: `mysqlsamplepassword`
14. Repeat password for the MySQL "root" user: `mysqlsamplepassword`

But if your problem is fail to interpret php, follow the instruction to enable your php first.

1. `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf`
2. look for php_admin_value engine off, between  and
3. Add `#` in front of `php_admin_value engine off` to disable it.
4. **REMEMBER! Don't change the value php_admin_value engine from off to on!**
5. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Wish it helps!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the port in which Apache is listening on, default is 80;

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf`

look for the Listen port should look like

`Listen 80`

if that port is diffrent in order to get into phpmyadmin your url must point to that port

example

`localhost:port/phpmyadmin/`

change the port number to the one you have in the /etc/apache2/ports.conf