# localhost/phpmyadmin not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apache2, php, phpmyadmin, php7

recently fresh installed `Ubuntu 16.04` removing `Ubuntu 14.04`.

I am trying to setup LAMP on local machine and have installed `PHP7.0`, `mySql` and `phpMyadmin`.

All is working fine, `http://localhost` is working `http://localhost/info.php` is working but while accessing `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` it is giving `HTTP ERROR 500` `The localhost page isn't working`
[image: phpmyadmin error]

> Update : /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskEntry ::= { dskTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: netSnmpAgentMIB ::= { netSnmpModuleIDs 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmFanSensorsValue ::= { lmFanSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmFanSensorsDevice ::= { lmFanSensorsEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmFanSensorsIndex ::= { lmFanSensorsEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmTempSensorsValue ::= { lmTempSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmTempSensorsDevice ::= { lmTempSensorsEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmTempSensorsIndex ::= { lmTempSensorsEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchTable ::= { logMatch 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchMaxEntries ::= { logMatch 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLoggingEntry ::= { nsLoggingTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileErrorMsg ::= { fileEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileErrorFlag ::= { fileEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileMax ::= { fileEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileSize ::= { fileEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileName ::= { fileEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileIndex ::= { fileEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput2Table ::= { nsExtendObjects 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Table ::= { nsExtendObjects 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendConfigTable ::= { nsExtendObjects 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendNumEntries ::= { nsExtendObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Entry ::= { nsExtendOutput1Table 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuNumCpus ::= { systemStats 67 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawGuestNice ::= { systemStats 66 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawGuest ::= { systemStats 65 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawSteal ::= { systemStats 64 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssRawSwapOut ::= { systemStats 63 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssRawSwapIn ::= { systemStats 62 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawSoftIRQ ::= { systemStats 61 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssRawContexts ::= { systemStats 60 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssRawInterrupts ::= { systemStats 59 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIORawReceived ::= { systemStats 58 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIORawSent ::= { systemStats 57 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawInterrupt ::= { systemStats 56 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawKernel ::= { systemStats 55 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawWait ::= { systemStats 54 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawIdle ::= { systemStats 53 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawSystem ::= { systemStats 52 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawNice ::= { systemStats 51 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawUser ::= { systemStats 50 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuIdle ::= { systemStats 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuSystem ::= { systemStats 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuUser ::= { systemStats 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssSysContext ::= { systemStats 8 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssSysInterrupts ::= { systemStats 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIOReceive ::= { systemStats 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIOSent ::= { systemStats 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssSwapOut ::= { systemStats 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssSwapIn ::= { systemStats 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssErrorName ::= { systemStats 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIndex ::= { systemStats 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput2Entry ::= { nsExtendOutput2Table 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laEntry ::= { laTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheTable ::= { nsCache 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheEnabled ::= { nsCache 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheDefaultTimeout ::= { nsCache 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchEntry ::= { logMatchTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extEntry ::= { extTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfigLogging ::= { nsConfiguration 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfigDebug ::= { nsConfiguration 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleString ::= { netSnmpExampleScalars 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleSleeper ::= { netSnmpExampleScalars 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleInteger ::= { netSnmpExampleScalars 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmVoltSensorsValue ::= { lmVoltSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmVoltSensorsDevice ::= { lmVoltSensorsEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmVoltSensorsIndex ::= { lmVoltSensorsEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheEntry ::= { nsCacheTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugTokenTable ::= { nsConfigDebug 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugDumpPdu ::= { nsConfigDebug 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugOutputAll ::= { nsConfigDebug 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugEnabled ::= { nsConfigDebug 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoPassphrase ::= { ucdDemoPublic 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoUserList ::= { ucdDemoPublic 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoPublicString ::= { ucdDemoPublic 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoResetKeys ::= { ucdDemoPublic 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatName ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassExamples ::= { netSnmpExamples 255 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotifications ::= { netSnmpExamples 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleTables ::= { netSnmpExamples 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleScalars ::= { netSnmpExamples 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: nsVacmAccessTable ::= { netSnmpVacmMIB 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdShutdown ::= { ucdTraps 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdStart ::= { ucdTraps 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsTable ::= { lmSensors 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmVoltSensorsTable ::= { lmSensors 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmFanSensorsTable ::= { lmSensors 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmTempSensorsTable ::= { lmSensors 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensorsMIB ::= { lmSensors 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: mrEntry ::= { mrTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendConfigEntry ::= { nsExtendConfigTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostRowStatus ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostStorage ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostAddress ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostAddressType ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostName ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prEntry ::= { prTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotification ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 0 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostsTable ::= { netSnmpExampleTables 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpIETFWGTable ::= { netSnmpExampleTables 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassOID ::= { netSnmpPassEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassInteger ::= { netSnmpPassEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassIndex ::= { netSnmpPassEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: netSnmpVacmMIB ::= { netSnmpObjects 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsVersion ::= { netSnmpObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsMibRegistry ::= { netSnmpObjects 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsExtensions ::= { netSnmpObjects 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDLMod ::= { netSnmpObjects 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCache ::= { netSnmpObjects 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsErrorHistory ::= { netSnmpObjects 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfiguration ::= { netSnmpObjects 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactions ::= { netSnmpObjects 8 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoMIB ::= { ucdavis 14 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatch ::= { ucdavis 16 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileTable ::= { ucdavis 15 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdTraps ::= { ucdavis 251 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: systemStats ::= { ucdavis 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: mrTable ::= { ucdavis 102 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrs ::= { ucdavis 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: version ::= { ucdavis 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laTable ::= { ucdavis 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskTable ::= { ucdavis 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: memory ::= { ucdavis 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extTable ::= { ucdavis 8 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prTable ::= { ucdavis 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdSnmpAgent ::= { ucdavis 250 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdExperimental ::= { ucdavis 13 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdInternal ::= { ucdavis 12 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsModuleEntry ::= { nsModuleTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskErrorMsg ::= { dskEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskErrorFlag ::= { dskEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskUsedHigh ::= { dskEntry 16 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskUsedLow ::= { dskEntry 15 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskAvailHigh ::= { dskEntry 14 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskAvailLow ::= { dskEntry 13 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskTotalHigh ::= { dskEntry 12 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskTotalLow ::= { dskEntry 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskPercentNode ::= { dskEntry 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskPercent ::= { dskEntry 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskUsed ::= { dskEntry 8 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskAvail ::= { dskEntry 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskTotal ::= { dskEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskMinPercent ::= { dskEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskMinimum ::= { dskEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskDevice ::= { dskEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskPath ::= { dskEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskIndex ::= { dskEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOTable ::= { ucdDiskIOMIB 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLoggingGroup ::= { nsConfigGroups 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugGroup ::= { nsConfigGroups 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrErrMessage ::= { snmperrs 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrErrorFlag ::= { snmperrs 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrNames ::= { snmperrs 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrIndex ::= { snmperrs 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionTable ::= { nsTransactions 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogStatus ::= { nsLoggingEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogMaxLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogType ::= { nsLoggingEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogToken ::= { nsLoggingEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendResult ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutNumLines ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutputFull ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Line ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutLine ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendLineIndex ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyStart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrMessage ::= { laEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrorFlag ::= { laEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadFloat ::= { laEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadInt ::= { laEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laConfig ::= { laEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoad ::= { laEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laNames ::= { laEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laIndex ::= { laEntry 1 }
[Fri Apr 22 23:48:44.450632 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21483] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 22 23:48:44.450706 2016] [core:notice] [pid 21483] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

A few lines from log file

Comment: What does `/var/log/apache2/error.log` say?

Comment: have included a few lines from bottom from error.log file in question.

Answer (score 15):

You have two options

Enter these commands for the specific error if your prior configuration is okay:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-gettext php-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or remove and start a fresh install:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql*
sudo apt-get --purge remove phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server phpmyadmin php-gettext php-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: apt-get install php-gettext did it for me

Comment: Also check this https://askubuntu.com/a/19128/109526

Answer (score 4):

Check that when you configure phpmyadmin's http server setting that you select the server by pressing the spacebar and is it gets marked with an asterisk or it will not configure it.  The press "OK" to save it.

Comment: I had this problem - selection was highlighted but didn't press space bar to place asterisk.  Had to `sudo apt purge phpmyadmin` and then re-install to get the option again.  Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I had the same problem. Using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` I could easily reinstall phpmyadmin and select the correct option.

Answer (score 1):

install libapache2-mod-php and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

install php extension :

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

Comment: You should expand your answer by explaining how these two modules fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't choose an answer, maybe the problem is still open and it is similar to mine (PHP is not working - therefore phpmyadmin doesn't work).

I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 yesterday and also got PHP7 (instead of 5) in the process.
localhost worked for me, but the public_html directory in my home directory didn't.

Problem was the upgrade of PHP (in localhost I had an html-document which loaded perfectly, but PHP didn't work as expected). I had to edit
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.conf 
where PHP was disabled ( line 23: php_admin_value engine Off )
just had to make it a comment (with the editor of your choice add a "#" at the start of the line):

```
# php_admin_value engine Off
```

and restart the apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope that helps ... worked like a charm for me. ;-)